# select() not getting more than 1 action

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I made a server socket in C++ for Unix (TCP), that accepted only one client socket. Today, I attempted to make it accept multiple ones. For some reason, it ends up only accepting 1, and it's not receiving messages sent by the client that IS able to connect. I believe that the select function isn't working properly. FYI: I'm new to socket programming, so please understand if it's a stupid mistake.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define MAXCLIENTS 30

int main()
{
    //create a socket
    int listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //(returns int) - makes socket (returns what socket it is in terms of an int)
    if(listening < 0) //check if we were able to make a socket!
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't create socket!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //bind the socket to an IP/Port
    sockaddr_in hint{}; // This creates a structure for the ipv4 info of the socket.
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET; //set the family to ipv4
    hint.sin_port = htons(PORT); //set the port to the macro set above (use host-to-network-short to conver the int to the port)
    hint.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //set the ip to any address

    if(bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)) < 0) //attempt to bind socket (inticated by what number the `listening` socket is) to ip/port
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't bind to IP/Port" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //mark the socket for listening

    if(listen(listening, MAXCLIENTS) < 0 /*SOMAXCONN = maximum amount of connections, defined by sys/socket.h*/) //attempt to listen on the socket number indicated by `listening`
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't listen on the socket!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //FD_CLR() = Remove 1 from set
    //FD_SET() = Add to set
    //FD_ZERO() = Remove everything from set
    //FD_ISSET() = Check if something is part of a set

    fd_set master; //define the set

    int max_sd;
    int client_socks[MAXCLIENTS]{};

    while (true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&master); //make sure it's cleared

        FD_SET(listening, &master); //add the listening socket (server) to the set

        max_sd = listening; //max socket descriptor set to the listening socket (need this for the select func)

        for (int i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) {

            if (client_socks[i] > 0) //make sure the particular socket exists
            {
                FD_SET(client_socks[i], &master); //add it to the set
            }
            if (client_socks[i] > max_sd) //if the socket is greater than our current maximum socket descriptor
            {
                max_sd = client_socks[i];
            }
        }

        //wait for some action on any socket within the master fd (this will set the master fd_set to be equal to whatever socket had some action on it)
        int activity = select(max_sd + 1, &master, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        if (activity < 0) //error!
        {
            std::cerr << "Error while trying to select!" << std::endl;
        }

        int addrlen = sizeof(hint);

        if (FD_ISSET(listening, &master)) //if the select got that there was action on the listening (server) socket - most likely, a client socket is trying to connect!
        {
            int client_socket;
            client_socket = accept(listening, (sockaddr *) &hint, &addrlen); //accept the first client "waiting to get in"

            if (client_socket < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Something went wrong when trying to accept a client socket!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "New connection: " << inet_ntoa(hint.sin_addr) << " on port " << ntohs(hint.sin_port) << std::endl;

            if (send(client_socket, "Welcome to the socket party!", strlen("Welcome to the socket party!"), 0) != strlen("Welcome to the socket party!")) { //greetings!
                std::cerr << "Error when sending welcome message." << std::endl; //something went wrong ;(
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MAXCLIENTS; i++) //for each index, set client_sock to the address of the index of client_socks, so that we can set the value of it!
            {
                if(client_socks[i] == 0) //if this position is null (0)
                {
                    client_socks[i] = client_socket;
                }
            }
        }

        //else, there was action on a client socket (most likely a message is being sent!

        char buffer[2048]; //we need somewhere to store clients messages!

        for (int &client_sock : client_socks) //loop through the client sockets
        {
            if (client_sock != 0)
            {
                if (FD_ISSET(client_sock, &master) == 0) //check if the select got action on the particular index in the client_socks array
                {
                    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //make sure the buffer is clear!
                    if (read(client_sock, &buffer, 2048) == 0) //check if nothing was recieved from the client
                    {
                        getpeername(client_sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, (socklen_t*)&addrlen) < 0; //gets networking info, based off of which socket is passed (the if statement checks for errors). In addition, it sets the values of hint to the info from the passed socket

                        //print that the client disconnected
                        std::cout << "A client has disconnected! IP: " << inet_ntoa(hint.sin_addr) << " Port: " << ntohs(hint.sin_port) << std::endl;

                        close(client_sock); //close the socket
                        client_sock = 0; //set its value in the array to 0, so that we can reuse it!
                    }

                    //else, we got message from the client
                    for (int &socket : client_socks)
                        //if (socket != client_sock)
                        send(socket , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized variable `client_socks`. You probably meant to initialize it to all zeros, but you didn't.

Comment: That has no effect. It's automatically initialized to have all zeros.

Comment: A variable with static duration (aka a global variable) would be, but the automatic (aka local) variable like `client_socks` usually wouldn't be. Your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/v1sk0c

Comment: `FD_ISSET(client_sock, &master) == 0` checks that the bit is **not** set. Compare and contrast with `if (FD_ISSET(listening, &master))`

Comment: I don't understand. What are you wanting me to do?

Comment: I see. The second checks if FD_ISSET(listening, &master) is true, and the first one checks if it's equal to 0

Comment: Read  [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) and [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [select_tut(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html) and [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html). Consider using [libevent](https://libevent.org/) or [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c2023.html) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with it, though?

Comment: As a socket identifier may also be equal to 0, it is preferable to set client_socks[i] = -1 when the entry is free. So, instead of initializing it to 0 (which is a valid socket descriptor), initialize it to -1.

Comment: In the loop, to check if data is pending on a client socket, "if (FD_ISSET(client_sock, &master) == 0) " is wrong. It must be "if (FD_ISSET(client_sock, &master) != 0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `client_socks` variable must be initialised, as Igor said - just append braces: `int client_socks[MAXCLIENTS]{};`.

Then your `for (int &client_sock : client_socks)` loop doesn't ignore 0 values (which you obviously want to be a sentinel given "`if(client_socks[i] == 0) //if this position is null (0)`").  Inside that loop, add "if (client_sock[i] == 0) continue;`.  Because you try to` read` from descriptor 0, it will block waiting for keyboard input.

Further, if you wanted your code to be robust, you would make the listening socket non-blocking, as it's possible for that socket to select readable, but by the time your application goes to accept from it, the client connection attempt has already been dropped: then you'd block waiting to accept another client connection attempt that might never come, and not be servicing existing clients.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post to the code you told me to change/add. Now, the input stuff works, but the acceptance of other clients. doesn't.

Comment: @user9985211 Stack Overflow is really for getting help with specific problems, where you've drilled down and found something specific you can't fix - not getting entire programs working.  Fixing the code in your post just means what I've already written is of no value to people searching the site in future.  You should probably ask on another Stack Exchange site, but I'm not sure which provides such help.  Anyway, you should take the time to think through what your code does.  `client_socks[i] = client_socket;` called in a loop will populate every array element with the newly accepted int.

Comment: When it has data to read, you'll then try to read from the same client not once but `MAXCLIENTS` times in a row, without returning to accept further clients.  If you add more statements to `cout << ...interesting data...` as your program runs, you'll discover these things yourself.  Or, you could use an interactive debugger.